# Angular11 using function in *ngIf in the template is getting invoked many times. how to avoid

Tags: rxjs, angular11

I have the following code. I am using a function in *ngIf and it is being called many times. How to fix this? Can anyone help me with this?

```
        <button
            type="button"
            class="button primary"
            *ngIf="canComplete() | async"
            (click)="complete()"
        >
            <span *ngIf="!userCanCompleteAudit">Complete assigned sections</span>
            <span *ngIf="userCanCompleteAudit">Complete audit</span>
        </button>

canComplete() {
    return this.service.sub$.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.cancel$),
        take(1),
        map(
            (responses) =>
                responses.every((r) => r.valid)
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, `canComplete()` will indeed get invoked many times. More precisely, it will get invoked for every *change detection* cycle. So the question now is, what is a change detection cycle, how does it relate to your problem, and how can we build a solution with knowledge about it?

### Introduction to Change Detection

Whenever a user interacts with your app, be it by clicking any buttons on a page, or triggering an HTTP request for example, Angular by default, has to re-evaluate all *template expressions* in your component template (i.e. your HTML code). Or as we say it, *a change detection cycle is triggered*.

In your case, Angular will re-evaluate the following template expressions:

- the value of `canComplete() | async` (1st template expression),
- of `!userCanCompleteAudit` (2nd template expression),
- and of `userCanCompleteAudit` (3rd template expression).

Why does Angular have to re-evaluate the values of these template expressions, you ask? So that **when Angular determines that an expression's value has changed**, Angular will then update the *template view* (basically the DOM) accordingly.

For example, if your 2nd template expression `!userCanCompleteAudit` evaluates from previously `true` to now `false`, Angular will then remove `<span>Complete assigned sections</span>` from the DOM, as per your logic. On the other hand, if Angular finds out that `!userCanComplateAudit` did not change after checking said expression's current value, Angular leaves that `span` element alone and keeps it displayed.

##### When is an Expression Considered "Changed"?

How does Angular decide when a template expression has "changed"? Simple. [By default](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/#howdoesthedefaultchangedetectionmechanismwork), Angular:

1. gets the template expression's old value,
2. evaluates its new value,
3. then performs a [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) against the expression's old and new values.

If they are not strictly equal, Angular marks the template expression as changed, and updates the template view accordingly.

### Why Methods in Template Expression Execute Multiple Times

At this point, we now know that for every change detection cycle (e.g. user interactions), template expressions get re-evaluated as part of Angular's change detection mechanism. And there lies the problem.

For your 2nd template expression `canComplete() | async`, this means that:

1. For every change detection cycle, `canComplete() | async` is evaluated.
2. Every time `canComplete() | async` is evaluated, `canComplete()` method is called. (This in particular is the issue you're seeing.)
3. Every time `canComplete()` is called, a new observable object is returned from `this.service.sub$.pipe(...)`.
4. Every time an observable is returned from `canComplate()`, a new subscription instance is made in the template via the `async` pipe.
5. For every subscriptions made, the pipeline is run (calling `responses.every((r) => r.valid)` every time).

### How to Prevent Method From Executing Multiple Times

The answer to this is a case-to-case basis. Depending on the context of your code, you might have to apply at least one of the following:

- Setting your component's change detection strategy to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.
- Refactoring your method (that returns an observable) into a observable variable.
- Subscribing from the controller instead of the template.

Most likely in your case, and without diving too much into details, your best bet is to apply bullet 3: subscribe from your component's controller.

```ts
// your component controller
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  canComplete = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.sub$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map((responses) => responses.every((r) => r.valid)),
      takeUntil(this.cancel$)
    )
    .subscribe((canComplete) => this.canComplete = canComplete);
  }
}
```

```html
<button *ngIf="canComplete" class="...">...</button>
```